# Pygame is not displaying a grid or fps counter

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a rpg but i always get the issue when pygame dose not display I am using a youtube video to help my make this rpg but Its just not working the creator made a color module to help but it just dose not work I know there are better ways of making a fps counter feel free to improve it

```
import pygame, sys, time
from Scripts.UltraColor import *

pygame.init()


cSec = 0
cFrame = 0
FPS = 0

tile_size = 32

fps_font = pygame.font.Font("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", 20)

def show_fps():
    fps_overlay = fps_font.render(str(FPS), True, Color.Goldenrod)
    window.blit(fps_overlay, (0,0))

def create_window():
    global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
    window_width, window_hight = 800, 600
    window_title = "RPG"
    pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_hight), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)


def count_fps():
    global cSec, cFrame, FPS

    if cSec == time.strftime("%S"):
        cFrame += 1
    else:
        FPS = cFrame
        cFrame = 0
        cSec = time.strftime("%S")

create_window()

isRunning = True

while isRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False

    # LOGIC
    count_fps()

    # Render Graphics
    window.fill(Color.Black)


    # - Render Sinple Terrain Grid
    for x in range(0, 640, tile_size):
        for y in range(0, 480, tile_size):
            pygame.draw.rect(window, Color.White, (x, y, tile_size + 1, tile_size + 1), 1)

    show_fps()

    pygame.display.update


pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parentheses behind `pygame.display.update` to call this function and update the display: `pygame.display.update()`

I also recommend to use a [`pygame.time.Clock`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to limit the frame rate and get the fps. Calling `clock.tick(FPS)` makes sure that the game doesn't run faster than this frame rate. In the `show_fps` function you can just call `clock.get_fps()` to get the current frame rate.

```
import pygame


def show_fps(window, clock):
    fps_overlay = FPS_FONT.render(str(clock.get_fps()), True, GOLDENROD)
    window.blit(fps_overlay, (0, 0))


pygame.init()

FPS_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("Verdana", 20)
GOLDENROD = pygame.Color("goldenrod")

tile_size = 32
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

isRunning = True

while isRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False

    # Render Graphics
    window.fill((50, 50, 50))

    # Render Simple Terrain Grid
    for x in range(0, 640, tile_size):
        for y in range(0, 480, tile_size):
            pygame.draw.rect(
                window, (255, 255, 255),
                (x, y, tile_size+1, tile_size+1), 1)

    show_fps(window, clock)

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```